# Go Gorm: Many2Many using UUID's

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have a weird issue using Go Gorm with UUID's.

Imagine I had 2 Tables

```
type A struct {
  ID uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;primary_key;"`
  Bs []B `gorm:"many2many:a_bs;"`
  Data ...
}

type B struct {
  ID uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;primary_key;"`
  Data ...
}
```

Both have a `func (data *Data) BeforeCreate(tx *gorm.DB)` to create the uuid.

In a update function I am checking if the `B` already exists and if not create it. I logged it out and got a proper UUID back. I am then doing `a.Bs = append(a.Bs, newB)` and `...Save(&a)` which returns a foreign key constraint error.

Using a int64 on the `B` and changing nothing else results in the code working as expected.

Am I missing something? (Using postgres as DB).

Comment: make sure you've read the points made at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52414414/best-practices-on-primary-key-auto-increment-and-uuid-in-sql-databases before you decide to use a UUID as a primary DB key.